# How can I remember the difference between "lay" and "laid"?

Tags: word-choice, confusable, mnemonic

I often confuse *lay* and *laid*.  For instance, in selecting the appropriate word in these contexts:

> She lay/laid a hand on his arm.
>     He lay/laid across the bench lazily.
>     We lay/laid down our heavy load.

Is there a common mnemonic for remembering which to use, and when?

Answer (score 13):

The key here is recognizing that there are two verbs you are confusing yourself with.

The first verb has a present tense form of *lie*. This is an active verb on the person performing it. For example: I lie on the couch after work every day. The past tense version of the verb is *lay*. Example: I lay in bed all day yesterday.

The other verb has a present tense form of *lay*. This is a verb describing the action of placing something on a surface. For example: Please lay the book on the table. The past tense version of this verb is *laid*. Example: He laid the towel on the bench.

In short, first make sure you know which verb you're looking for, and then use the correct tense.

Comment: *Lying* being the action of placing oneself on a surface further enhances the confusion. No lie!

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky as it involves two separate but very closely related verbs, *to lay* and *to lie*, that share a common form—i.e. *lay* is both the present tense form of *to lay* and the past tense form of to lie.

The primary difference between [*to lay*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay) and [*to lie*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie) is that *to lay* is [transitive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/transitiveverb.htm), meaning it takes a [direct object](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/directobject.htm), while *to lie* is [intransitive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm) and does not take an object. The verbs have the following forms: to lay—**lay (present tense)**, laid (past tense), laid (past participle), and laying (present participle); and to lie—lie (present tense), **lay (past tense)**,lain (past participle), and lying (present participle).

So using that information, given that all three are in the simple past tense, I can tell that number one is *laid*, which has the direct object of *a hand*, and numbers two and three are *lay*, which have no object.

Here's where you may be getting tripped up: *laid* is a form of *to lay*, and *lay*, in the simple past, is a form of *to lie*. In other words, the word *lay* in numbers two and three is **not** connected to the verb *to lay.*

As long as you know what tense the examples are in, it's simply a matter of whether or not the verb has a direct object.