# I have a problem with ''lay'' and ''lie''

Tags: word-choice

I was studying english and saw this sentence and i could not decide which of them would be better to use? (I am not a native just student)

Mesopotamia was suitable for ancient merchants, but the dangerous passages that … between the towns ... the pillage of many cowboys.

Options were like:
lying/have meant - lie/meant - laid/would mean - lay/were meant - are lying/have meant

Comment: We have a sister site which is designed for better and faster answers to Qs of this type: [ELL.se].

Comment: Why in the world was this migrated when it was clearly a duplicate of an existing question on ELU?

Comment: Also see [How can I remember the difference between “lay” and “laid”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23) and [Correct usage of “Lie” or “Lay” and their respective tenses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111306)

Answer (score 0):

Lie is something you do to yourself, lay is what you do to other people or objects. "I'm going to lie down now." "The baby is tired, I should lay him down."

Comment: Right. _Lie_ meaning 'recline' is intransitive, whereas _lay_ is the causative of _lie_ (it means 'cause to lie'), and causatives are always transitive. This gets confusing because the past tense of _lie_ is _lay_ (the principal parts are _lie, lay, lain_), like its causative, which is a regular verb, with _-d_ past tense and participle (_lay, laid, laid_). And also by the fact that there's another, regular, verb _lie_ meaning 'tell an untruth'. Here's a [diagram of how it works inside](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler//threekindsofword.pdf).

Comment: But for many speakers, _lie_ and _lay_ have mostly merged.